# Getting Variable "@xml_files" will not stay shared at ... line

Tags: perl

I have the following Perl code:

```
sub merge_xml {

  foreach my $repository ('repo1', 'repo2') {
    my @xml_files;

    sub match_xml {
      my $filename = $File::Find::dir . '/' . $_;
      if ($filename =~ m%/(main|test)\.xml$%) {
        push(@xml_files, $filename);
      }
    }

    find(\&match_xml, $repository);

    print Dumper(\@xml_files);
  }
}
```

And I am getting the warning:

```
Variable "@xml_files" will not stay shared at ./script/src/repair.pl line 87.
```

How does one fix this?

PS find as in [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from [zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim) I came up with:

```
sub merge_xml {

  foreach my $repository ('repo1', 'repo2') {
    my @xml_files;

    my match_xml = sub {
      my $filename = $File::Find::dir . '/' . $_;
      if ($filename =~ m%/(main|test)\.xml$%) {
        push(@xml_files, $filename);
      }
    };

    find($match_xml, $repository);

    print Dumper(\@xml_files);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

"Nested" named subs in fact aren't -- they're compiled as separate subroutines, and so having them written as "nested" can only be misleading.

Further, this creates a problem since the "inner" subroutine supposedly closes over the variable `@xml_files` that it uses, which gets redefined on each new call, being lexical. But the sub, built at compile-time and not being a lexical closure, only keeps the refernce to the value at first call and so it works right only upon the first call to the outer sub (`merge_xml` here).

We do get the warning though. With `use diagnostics;` (or see it [in perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag#Variable-%22%25s%22-will-not-stay-shared))

> Variable "$x" will not stay shared at -e line 1 (#1)
> (W closure) An inner (nested) named subroutine is referencing a
> lexical variable defined in an outer named subroutine.
>
> When the inner subroutine is called, it will see the value of
> the outer subroutine's variable as it was before and during the *first*
> call to the outer subroutine; in this case, after the first call to the
> outer subroutine is complete, the inner and outer subroutines will no
> longer share a common value for the variable.  In other words, the
> variable will no longer be shared.
>
> This problem can usually be solved by making the inner subroutine
> anonymous, using the sub {} syntax.  When inner anonymous subs that
> reference variables in outer subroutines are created, they
> are automatically rebound to the current values of such variables.

So pull out that "inner" sub (`match_xml`) and use it normally from the "outer" one (`merge_xml`). In general you'd pass the reference to the array (`@xml_files`) to it; or, since in this case one cannot pass to `File::Find`'s `find`, can have the array in such scope so to be seen as needed.

Or, since the purpose of `match_xml` is to be [find's "wanted" function](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find#The-wanted-function), can use an anonymous sub for that purpose so there is no need for a separate named sub

```
find( sub { ... }, @dirs );
```

Or store that coderef in a variable, as shown in [Ed Heal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65174755/4653379)

```
my $wanted_coderef = sub { ... };
find( $wanted_coderef, @dirs );
```

Comment: I have a problem doing that as `find` is [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find)

Comment: @EdHeal OK -- but the `find` call will still see the sub, even if outside.  Also, you can call `find` with a coderef -- `find( sub { ... }, @dirs );` so have the sub "inline" so to say.

Comment: @EdHeal Ah, right, you mean you can't pass the array -- of course not.  So have it in the scope so that `find` sees it.  Edited the answer, will add another way for hiding that array

Comment: @EdHeal Got to update, and in the meanwhile you beat me to the coderef -- the nicest way in my opinion, if one needs it separately.  (Note that that is then a proper closure ... probably useless in this use though.)

Comment: See also [lexical subroutines](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Lexical-Subroutines)

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest another alternative.  By using a factory function, you can eliminate the need to hand write a `find` subroutine each time.

A factory is a function that generates another function (or subroutine in this case).  You feed it some parameters and it creates a custom subroutine with those parameters bolted in.  My example uses a closure but you could also build it with a string `eval` if the closure is costly for some reason.

```perl
sub match_factory {
  my ($filespec, $array) = @_;

  # Validate arguments
  die qq{File spec must be a regex, not "$filespec"\n}
    unless ref $filespec eq "Regexp";
  die qq{Second argument must be an array reference, not "$array"\n} 
    unless ref $array eq "ARRAY";

  # Generate an anonymous sub to perform the match check
  # that creates a closure on $filespec and $array
  my $matcher = sub {
    # Automatically compare against $_
    m/$filespec/ and
    push(@$array, $File::Find::name);
  };

  return $matcher;
}


sub merge_xml {
  my @repos = @_ # or qw/foo bar .../;

  foreach my $repository (@repos) {
    my @matched_files;
    find(
      match_factory( qr/\/(main|test)\.xml$/, \@matched_files ),
      $repository
    );
    print Dumper(\@matched_files);
  }

}
```

HTH